# dependencies ‘rJava’, ‘Rserve’ are not available for package ‘RHive’

Tags: r

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘rJava’, ‘Rserve’ are not available for package ‘RHive’
* removing ‘/root/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RHive’
```

How do I fix this?

I am trying to run:

```
R CMD INSTALL RHive_2.0-0.10.tar.gz
```

Directly uploading RHive to

R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2
gives

```
Error in library(RHive) : ‘RHive’ is not a valid installed package
```

I could run Rserve only by using

```
/usr/lib64/R/bin/R CMD /home/rstudio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rserve/libs//Rserve
```

Comment: have you tried to install `rJava` directly? http://www.rforge.net/rJava/files/

Comment: Where should I install it? with install.packages , it got installed in R lib folder but just that RHive can't see it or something

Comment: Install it to ' /x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/'  where your other packages are stored, too.

Comment: rJava and rServe package exist there. Just that RHive cannot find it

Comment: @J_F: Any idea?